# Should a View bind indirectly to properties in a Model in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Let's say I've got a View.  It's `DataContext` is bound to a `ViewModel` and the `ViewModel` exposes a `Model` property.

- Is it `MVVM`like to bind fields in the `View` to properties in the `Model` (e.g. `Binding Path=Model.FirstName`)?
- Should the `Model` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

My team are using Prism and MVVM in WPF.  A lot of the Prism examples bind indirectly to the `Model`.  I personally have my doubts that this is the correct approach.  I think stuff in the model should expose **behaviour** (not just at the property level) and should communicate important events by, er, `event`s - that clients can subscribe to or not.

I think that by having domain/model objects implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` somehow says to the world that it's UI/UX aware and kind of introduces some redundancy in the `ViewModel`s.

What do you think?  What works for you?  A clear distinction between `View`/`ViewModel`/`Model` or a hybrid as used by the Prism examples?

Comment: Considering that you cannot bind to fields, no.  Properties are a different matter...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have seen many people implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` directly in their `Model` and similarly I have seen people doing it in `ViewModel` as well.

I prefer and do this(implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`) in `ViewModel`. I agree with you it sometimes create redundancy in `ViewModel` but I prefer a clear distinction/separatation between `ViewModel` and `Model` and what their purpose should be. To me `Model` is just literally a `Model`. It is just representation of my `Business Data` nothing more nothing less. To me it should not cause any change in `View` (through notify property changed event). `View` should talk to `ViewModel` and `ViewModel` should use `Model`. I don't like View directly affecting the `Model`. I don't like using `Model.FirstName` because to me it seems like going against `MMVM` by telling `View` what is in `Model`

Comment: What I have 10 different instances of the model and each instance has 20 properties, would it not be a pain in the ass to exlpicitly expose all thos properties in ViewModel?

Comment: @AnkurSharma I agree, it would be but as I said that's how some people like me like it even though there is pain. And I explained my reasons in the answer